# Skipped result xml file on testNG Suite

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have created a test using the TestNG framework in Java in Eclipse and want to execute my tests through an XML file by running it through the testNG Suit.

the file system of my folder is illustrated in the following Link screenshot:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIa1p.png)

**my java code:**

```js
package a;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Amir {
 
        @Test
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      
  System.out.println("Test Test");    
   
  } 

}
```

**my xml code:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="a.Amir"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When i execute above xml using TestNg Suit, on eclipse console i received log as:

[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Amir\workspace\SmartAir.co.il\testng.xml

===============================================

Suite

## Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

===============================================

Could anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Could you please add verbose level 10 to your xml file (in suite tag) and paste the output here ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I have to delete the `(String[] args)` because TestNG tests do not take any arguments.